# Are there any foreshadowings of Adam Warlock prior to GotG Vol.2?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, guardians-of-the-galaxy

In the post-credits scene in *Guardians of the Galaxy* Vol. 2, Adam Warlock makes an appearance (in his cocoon) in the MCU.

Referring to this scene:

[image: Adam's cocoon]

Other than and prior to this, is there any other foreshadowing of Adam Warlock in the MCU?

Comment: Before anyone mentions the cocoon in GotG1, [Gunn has gone on the record saying that that was never intended as the cocoon](https://www.inverse.com/article/31318-guardians-of-the-galaxy-james-gunn-adam-warlock-easter-egg)

Comment: @phantom42 To me it seems like it was intended to be Warlock, but only as a joke, and that fans took it more seriously than he anticipated. I could be wrong, though.

Comment: @RogueJedi Gunn's interview reply: `“I made a mistake in the first one, because I put something that looks like Adam Warclok’s cocoon in the Collector’s museum,” he said. “For me, at the time, I was just making up fun stuff to put in the Collector’s museum. I didn’t know how seriously people were gonna take the Easter eggs.”` so it seems that he "accidentally" put something that looked like a cocoon in there

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Yes**

> The character was previously teased as an Easter egg in 2013’s Thor: The Dark World, in a mid-credits scene directed by Gunn. In the Collector’s museum, Adam Warlock’s cocoon is spotted as one of the Collector’s prized relics, alongside a Chitauri soldier and Howard the Duck. Now, in an interview with IGN, director James Gunn admits inserting Adam Warlock’s cocoon — or at least, something that looks like it — was a “mistake.”
>
> I made a mistake in the first one, because I put something that looks like Adam Warclok’s cocoon in the Collector’s museum,” he said. “For me, at the time, I was just making up fun stuff to put in the Collector’s museum. I didn’t know how seriously people were gonna take the Easter eggs.” This being the MCU, it was inevitable fans would pour over every detail with a fine-toothed comb.

But the Easter egg from Thor:The Dark World was retconned and later revealed to be "someone from the Warlock species.

> In 2014, James Gunn confirmed that the cocoon in Guardians of the Galaxy and Thor 2 was Adam Warlock’s, but clarified when the sequel released that it actually belonged to a member of Warlock’s species. This effectively retconned the first tease. The implication of the first one was that Adam already existed and could be born at any time, while the second dropped his name and gave him a specific purpose.

So there was a tease to Adam Warlock but to make place for him in the second Gotg movie they retconned it, but before Gotg 2 it was a tease to Adam Warlock nonetheless.